# SSRS 2005 modifying report query now get preview error .. the filtervalue expression non-existing report parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, filter

I made a copy of an SSRS 2005 report. Using the same datasource but with a new query with new tables. I can query my data, but in preview I get

```
**The FilterValue expression for the table xxxxx refers to an non-exiting report parameter 'yyyy'**
```

I don't want a filter. Where do remove that filterValue and the parameter in my report - I can't seem to find it?  It appears to be an old entry in the report.

I'm looking at the new dataset and do not see anything under Parameters or filters. And when I excute the query it returns data.

I am seeing filters in the report definition, but I do I safely remove them using the Design tool?

Answer (score 2):

From the error message supplied, it appears that the filter is associated with the table on the report, not the dataset.

Locate the table referenced in the error while in design view, and right-click -> properties. Take a look at the filter tab, and remove the invalid reference.

Screenshot of the filter tab from Report Builder 3.0:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening the .rdl file in a text editor and search for the report parameter 'yyyy'.

Examining the surrounding XML tags might help you find an element name or similar that you can find in the properties box back in the designer.